# Should I use an object or individual props for commonly-prefixed props on a React component?

Tags: reactjs

As above, should I use an object or individual props for those with are commonly-prefixed on a React component?

Either:

`<Callout buttonUrl="/test" buttonText="Test">`

or:

`<Callout button={{ url: "/test", text: "Test" }}>`

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "commonly prefixed". In any case, using individual props is much more in keeping with the general React pattern.

Comment: Sorry, with a common prefix - in this case `button`. Thank you!

Comment: I think it depends on your component.  For this simple `Callout` component, I would keep url and text separate as mentioned, but once you have complicated components, it might make sense to group some props together.

Comment: Also, if the `Callout` component is a button, I would also name it `CalloutButton`, then you wouldn't need to prefix your props with button.

Comment: Good thinking, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to have separate properties, I think of a component props as the parameters of a API, I want them to be as expressive as possible and not to close it in a object that can grow to have extra unnecessary properties.

And also I don't see a reason to need to prepend all of the properties with `button`, if the component is a button you might had `Button` to the component's name.

But these are rules I try to impose to myself (as personal preference), but they are not set in stone... There are cases when it might make more sense to pass a object instead of passing dozens of properties. I think the most important thing is to set a standard to yourself (or your team) and stick with it as much as possible, making your code more readable for you and others working in your project.